# Is it possible in C++ to type multiple lines of string outputs without have to continually add the prefix "cout"?

Tags: c++, syntax

I just started learning C++. I have seen examples of coders typing code like this...

```
int main() {

    cout << "hello";
         << "world";
    return 0;
}
```

but when I tried that it seemed to me that I have to write it like this...

```
int main() {
    cout << "hello";
    cout << "world";
    return 0;
}
```

How can I do this like the original example shows?

Comment: Use `std::endl` perhaps? And you've certainly not seen an example like your 1st one, that's simply not valid c++ code, or at least doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: The examples you have seen don't have a `;` at the end of the first line, only on the last line.  Remove the `;` after `<< "hello"` and the code compiles fine.

Comment: Your second example should not make multiple lines of output. What I mean is there is no white space at all: [https://ideone.com/52SM4Y](https://ideone.com/52SM4Y)  so the output is `helloworld` not hello and world on separate lines.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the first example you put won't even compile. There's no left-hand operand for the `<<` operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might mean:

```cpp
int main() {

    cout << "hello"  // <- no trailing `;`
         << "world";
    return 0;
}
```

That will print:

```
helloworld
```

If you wanted then on separated rows, you can write:

```cpp
int main() {

    cout << "hello\n"
         << "world\n";
    return 0;
}
```

That will produce:

```
hello
world
```

But, there is another, less known, feature of the compiler - concatenation
of raw strings:

```cpp
int main() {
    cout << "hello"
            "world";
    return 0;
}
```

That will also work. This too gives `helloworld` as output.

Comment: yes! thank you. I didn't take into consideration the ; would be the issue. I have figured it out. thank you!